# Classification of the questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I just realised that the questions on the site are too mixed up together. On the main page, a question about Newtonian Mechanics is often side-by-side with a question on the standard model/general relativity/string theory etc. I think this is quite messy so a classification would be quite good. Not by tags, but by categories. According to me, the following would be a good classification (but by no means am I suggesting to be final):

- Non-Relativistic Classical Mechanics

  - Newtonian Mechanics
  - Thermodynamics
  - Maybe statistical mechanics?
  - Optics
  - Wave mechanics and oscillators
  - Hamiltonian Mechanics
  - Lagrangian Mechanics
  - Newtonian Gravitation
  - Maxwellian Electromagnetism
- Relativity

  - Special Relativity
  - General Relativity
  - Alternatives to General Relativity (Einstein-Cartan theory, etc.)
- Quantum Mechanics

  - Old Quantum Theory
  - Heisenberg Matrix mechanics
  - Schrodinger Wave mechanics
  - Feynman Path Integral mechanics
  - Scattering
- Quantum Field Theory

  - Relativistic Quantum Mechanics (Klein-Gordon Equation, Weyl Equation, Dirac Equation, etc.)
  - Quantum Chromodynamics
  - Electroweak theory
  - Quantum Electrodynamics
  - Higgs theory
  - Standard model
- Quantum Gravity and Unification theories

  - String theory
  - Loop Quantum Gravity
  - Maybe Kaluza-Klein?
  - etc. (GUTs, preon models, and other attempts to Quantum Gravity)

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/could-we-make-tags-imply-other-tags) is similar. I don't really like this request -- separating stuff on the main page may not give a good overview of the site.

Comment: That will create something like Yahoo answers . Different categories can be seen by users........ But some categories will be seriously ignored.

Comment: It's neither interesting nor clever. This website is not a library, so it doesn't need a Dewey classification. The search engine is good enough to know if a similar question than yours already exists. Tags can be added, too, such that the tagging is sufficiently precise I believe. I voted down. Thanks for having spend time explaining your idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Not gonna happen.

The site is built to use tags for categorization rather than a hierarchy, and this is a good thing because tagging is more flexible than hierarchies which always suffer from problems relating to

- difficult to categorize questions
- questions that span disciplines

There are several things that you can do to control the presentation.

- Use the [Favorite and Ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) mechanism, and view the [front page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) rather than the [questions page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions) because the front page is weighted by your favorite tags (or by your [frequented tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108224/documentation-for-frequented-tags-feature) if you haven't specified your favorites)
- Use [tag subscriptions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/tag-favorites-and-tag-subscriptions/) or the  [RSS feeds](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)
- [Search by tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/searching)