# Add "Interesting" questions tab to front page

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

StackOverflow has a tab for questions entitled "Interesting" that is based on favorited tags and history:

[image: Interesting tab]

Is it possible to get said tab on physics.SE based on recent discussions such as [Is Physics Stack Exchange getting Cluttered?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4382/is-physics-stack-exchange-getting-cluttered) in order to help users organize the questions better?

Comment: More information in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current setup for the "interesting" tab looks at the last 3,000 posts, using [various user- and post-specific metrics](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) to display 90 personalized posts; that makes sense, since Stack Overflow gets over twice that every day. We could look at less than that, but...

...At 42 questions per day, Physics.SE's homepage already displays most recent activity on the site... to *everyone*. The logic used for the "interesting" tab as it's currently set up wouldn't accomplish much.

We've been looking at different ways to customize the homepage; [this is still very much experimental](http://kevinmontrose.com/2013/05/22/your-future-on-stack-overflow/), but at some point we hope to have something better than either the current home page or SO's "interesting" tab. Until then...

Comment: In Physics stack exchange questions get replaced with new ones roughly every day. And good questions require more time then one day to be answered. To me even if a person accesses the site even once a week, He should be able to access and answer important relevant to his interests. If you think about it even 40 questions is a lot of activity, especially in a subject like physics.

Comment: Yes, this site need a different way to customize the home page, and I hope the organization scheme implemented in SO, will also be useful for Physics.SE in some way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm not married to the idea of an "interesting" tab, I was merely trying to be diplomatic since I was asked to post about it. FWIW, the predictor thing linked in the post in your answer is spot on for all my accounts.