# (Almost) ten years of Physics Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

This is something we should flag early if we want to do something in time for when it happens: **the tenth anniversary of Physics Stack Exchange will happen in three months.**

Specifically, the private beta started on 2 November 2010 and the public beta started on 9 November 2010.

So: do we want to do something to celebrate that fact? (For comparison, MO turned ten last year; [this thread](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4270) and [this one](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4353) show what happened.)

Given that everybody who answered the question "where do you see yourself in five years" in 2015 got it massively wrong, I don't think that in-person meetups are appropriate at this time. But maybe we can organize some form of video meetup? Or, failing that, just organizing some tenth-anniversary celebratory swag?

Comment: interesting how this post https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4382/ of 7yrs ago refers to cluttering with 40 questions per day.  We all well beyond that in all and every sense.

Comment: Good idea. They unfortunately didn't do it on Stack Overflow (only mentioned weeks or months after). It was a missed opportunity to reflect on the history of the site and remind people why it existed in the first place ([Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) and all).

Comment: Yes, this should be celebratory, infact everyone should get bonus rep :P

Comment: Where is this 2015 post about "where you see yourself in 5 years"?

Comment: @StevenSagona I don't think that post exists. I think Emilio means that none of us would've said five years ago that we would be in the middle of a pandemic today.

Comment: A bit O/T: where can a member see when he/she joined P.SE?

Comment: @Gert Just go to your profile. you can see how long ago you joined. But it's not precise. (e.g. mine says 2 years and 8 months ago)

Comment: @BioPhysicist The tooltip on the `Member for` datum on the profile, like most other timing information on SE, has a precise timestamp, down to the second, of when the account was created. For yours, it reports 2017-12-19 19:45:41 UTC.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks.  I figured there was a way to access it. I wasn't trying to suggest there was no way to get the exact time.

Comment: Answering high-scoring, unanswered questions (examples [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27190/60151), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27699/60151)), from years back could be considered celebrating the past, perhaps there can be a combined effort on this.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty anything going on that front?

Answer (score 26):

I guess I'll kick it off with an idea: how about a chat session or two? I know we don't have regular chat sessions like we used to, but perhaps just a time at which anyone interested can converge in the chat room to exchange stories or whatever they like.

I'm not necessarily saying that this would be better than a video meetup or any of the other ideas, but I figure it is something that would be kind of on theme for us, and probably wouldn't be hard to organize.

Comment: Though I certainly hope this isn't the only answer that gets posted...

Answer (score 18):

Here are a few ideas off the top of my head:

- Maybe we can revisit the top few questions from each year and have a discussion on them?
- Perhaps have a separate chat room where people post how their lives have changed in the past ten years.
- Those with access to site analytics maybe can share a glimpse of the growth?

Don’t know how feasible these ideas are. But regardless, celebratory swag should happen!

Answer (score 7):

Because Monday November 2nd 2020 is just 1 day before the US election, it is perhaps better to officially celebrate the 10th anniversary of Phys.SE on Monday November 9th 2020?